# Neo4j error, Failed to start Neo Server on port[80]

Tags: database, neo4j, port, graph-databases

I have a Neo4j database using port7474, this database works fine.
Then I got a new database,in the beginning, it also worked, but after several days, it can not start. The error messages show "Failed to start Neo Server on port[80]", so I change the \conf\neo4j-server.properties, from port 80 to port 7474, still can not start.

What is the probelm?
The old neo4j database can still work, what is wrong with the new one?

Answer (score 0):

This error message indicates that there is one `neo4j-server.properties` file setting the port to 80. Maybe you've downloaded and installed multiple versions of Neo4j to different locations. Use a global search e.g. `find / -name neo4j-server.properties` (or do the same via point&click when being on Windows) to identify them.

Comment: Yes,i have old neo4j database. but even if i changed all old database port, the new database still can not run.Actually no matter which port i give the new port, it allways fail. do you know why?

Comment: did you restart the database with changed configs? Which OS?

Comment: Yes restart it after change, but our database is actually started by click the file "Neo4j.bat" in bin folder. I use windows7